# Define Javascript type for Gutenberg blocks (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to create custom blocks for Gutenberg, using ReactJS.
I'm trying to render HTML through the render() function, but I get the **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"** error.

Now, I've read that I should make sure I'm defining the script type as **text/babel** to render the HTML properly, but as I'm adding my JS files through the **wp_register_script()** wordpress function, I have to clue how to do that.

Let me know if you need more details, thanks!

Comment: Are you not using a build script to compile your code? If you're trying to write the React JSX directly, you will run into problems. Have a look at https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block - it's a great starting point for you to write your own blocks.

Comment: interesting, i'll take a look @raffjones !

Answer (score 0):

**First enqueu your script for functio.php file :**

```
function gutenberg_boilerplate_block() {
    wp_register_script(
        'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5-step01',
        get_theme_file_uri( '/js/test.js' ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-components', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-editor' )
    );

    register_block_type( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5/hello-world-step-01', array(
        'editor_script' => 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5-step01',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_boilerplate_block' );
```

**Put Your Code test.js :**

**For example :**

```
var el = wp.element.createElement,
    registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
    blockStyle = { backgroundColor: '#900', color: '#fff', padding: '20px' };

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-es5/hello-world-step-01', {
    title: 'Hello World (Step 1)',

    icon: 'universal-access-alt',

    category: 'layout',

    edit: function() {
        return el( 'p', { style: blockStyle }, 'Hello editor.' );
    },

    save: function() {
        return el( 'p', { style: blockStyle }, 'Hello saved content.' );
    },
} );
```

**Learn Gutenberg, Now Click This Url :**

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/

Comment: This solution isn't using HTML templates though, that's the method I'm currently stuck using.

Comment: Ohk, Let's see this link :

https://github.com/Invulu/organic-profile-block/blob/master/block/profile/block.js

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to render react element directly.

```
const element = <h1>Hello JSX</h1>;
```

This should be compiled into:

```
var element = React.createElement(
  "h1",
  null,
  "Hello JSX"
);
```